# Sharing O365 Calendar via Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure, calendar, office365, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am able to create a calendar via Microsoft Graph in O365 with below API

`POST v1.0/users/{alias}/calendars`

I am not able to find an API which can be used to share the created calendar to another user. Is there an API which I can use to share this calendar to a another user.

It is possible to share via outlook as below, but I am not finding an API to do this via Microsoft Graph.

[image]

Comment: That's not possible if I'm correct. An admin can only share the whole mailbox and not only the calendar. Only users can do that.

Comment: Hi @FerronSW, Thanks, I am looking at delegated permission in users context, Not admin. My scenario is user1 creates a calendar with Graph and now wants to share that calendar with user2.